# If result from matching condition is null/does not exist in workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

In my workflow, I return the ID from some list that I use as a look up based on some matching text field that exists in both lists. I use that ID to set a look up field in my current item. 
If that text value that I'm searching for does not exist, how can I make sure that it goes through with the rest of the workflow, assuming I can't just move this part to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged what the ID was returning when it didn't match: "0" so I just put in a condition that starts "If ID *not equals* **0**"...